# enabling ECMP in linux

Tags: linux, routing

if i want to use ECMP (Equal Cost Multi Path) in a linux machine acting as a router, is it sufficient to have just multiple next-hop addresses in the routing table for the same destination with equal cost? Or should I configure anything more?

Answer (score 1):

This is enough, as long as `CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_MULTIPATH=y` is defined in the kernel configuration.